# generate combinations from list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, combinations

generate all combinations from list of numbers,the combinations can be pair of two numbers

example 1 :  list of 2 numbers [1,2]

```
[
[[1],[2]],
[[1,2]]
]
```

example 2 :  list of 3 numbers [1,2,3]

```
[
[[1], [2], [3]],
[[1], [2, 3]],
[[1, 3], [2]],
[[1, 2], [3]]
]
```

example 3 :  list of 4 numbers [1,2,3,4]

```
[
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]],
[[1], [2, 4], [3]],
[[1], [2, 3], [4]],
[[1, 4], [2], [3]],
[[1, 3], [2], [4]],
[[1, 2], [3], [4]],
[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
[[1, 3], [2, 4]],
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
]
```

The current implementation works but it is slow for list of 10 numbers

```
def get_all_order_combinations(nums, first=True):
    if first and len(nums) == 1:
        return [[[nums[0]]]]
    if len(nums) == 2:
        nums.sort()
        return [
            [[nums[0]], [nums[1]]],
            [[nums[0], nums[1]]]
        ]
    else:
        all_results = []
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            temp_list = list(nums)
            del temp_list[i]
            current_num = nums[i]
            results = get_all_order_combinations(temp_list, False)
            results = [[[current_num]]+result for result in results]
            for result in results:
                result.sort()
                if result not in all_results:
                    all_results.append(result)
        if len(nums) >= 4:
            for comb in combinations(nums, 2):
                comb = list(comb)
                results = get_all_order_combinations(
                    [n for n in nums if n not in comb]
                    ,False
                )
                results = [[comb]+result for result in results]
                for result in results:
                    result.sort()
                    if result not in all_results:
                        all_results.append(result)
        return all_results
```

Comment: Please consider moving your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the python in-built "itertools" package.
It is optimised to create combinations, which may solve your concerns with speed. Online searches will yield results on how to use it.
Here is one example:
[geeksforgeeks Permutation and Combination in Python with itertools](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/)

My attempt at reproducing example 2 using itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations
  

num_list = [1, 2, 3]
output_list = []

for i in range(1, len(num_list)):
    comb = combinations(num_list, i)
    obtained_combinations = []
    for combination in list(comb):
        
        if i != 1:
            temp_list = num_list.copy()
            for selected_number in combination:
                temp_list.remove(selected_number)

            obtained_combinations.append([temp_list, list(combination)])
        else:
            obtained_combinations.append(list(combination))

    output_list.append(obtained_combinations)



print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2], [3]], [[[3], [1, 2]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[1], [2, 3]]]]
```

Comment: I see, sorry I did not have enough reputation to add comments.. I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you for you answer,  it works only for example 1 & 2 , but not for example 3